# не грузится картинка из css файла

Tags: html, css

не грузится картинка из css файла хотя все подключено верно вот код

```
<head>
    <title>123</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="top">
            sd
        </div>
        <div class="middle">

        </div>
        <div class="bottom">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

и css

```
.top{
  background-image: url(../images/WKR8byV.png);
}
```

Comment: проблема не в ссылке точно, тк картинка грузится если в инспекторе ее открыть

Comment: Сделайте рабочий сниппет

Answer (score 0):

решил с помощью увеличение области где грузится картинка

Comment: что это значит?